# Update table using inner join on several fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update, inner-join

i have this query:

```
update B
set B.NBR_OF_BACKUP=B.NBR_OF_BACKUP - 1
FROM BACKUP_TABLE B
INNER JOIN tbl I ON B.ID_BACKUP=i.id_backup
```

in the table `tbl` i have:

```
ID_BACKUP ID_IMAGES
1         2
1         3
1         4
6         3
```

my query is updating only for distinct `id_backup`
but i need also to update the table `BACKUP_TABLE` as many times as the same `id_backup` is in the table `tbl`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is this:

```
update B
set B.NBR_OF_BACKUP=I.NBR_OF_BACKUP - 1
FROM BACKUP_TABLE B
INNER JOIN (SELECT id_backup, count(*) as nbr_of_backup FROM tbl GROUP BY id_backup) I 
ON B.ID_BACKUP=i.id_backup
```